# Preserve QueryString parameter in Sharepoint iFrame

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, query-string

the problem: when sending out marketing emails we should track on the website whether user came by a link from an email. The site is hosted in SharePoint 2003 environment and our *.aspx page is in an iFrame. How can I pass QueryString parameter from SharePoint URL to the iFrame URL?

In other words, if user comes by URL:

```
http://mainsite.com/default.aspx?email=1
```

then my iFrame should point to:

`http:/iframesite.com/page.aspx?email=1`, otherwise to `http:/iframesite.com/page.aspx`

I don't have development control over the CMS, only editorial one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are the parent and the child in different domains? If so, your only option is to set the proper URL in the parent site (the child can't get anything from it's parent if the parent is in a different domain, browsers don't allow that for security reasons).